# Text in Text Field Off Center

Tags: android, android-edittext, androidx

Is it possible to have text in an editText field be slightly off center?

When using the endIconMode to insert a clear field option, it would look better if the text was slightly to the left of center so it didn't almost run into the clear text.

```
endIconMode="clear_text"
```

[image]

I imagine I could manually create the clear x with an image, but I am hoping there is a more straightforward way to accomplish this.

Comment: how about using margins ?

Comment: A margin relative to what?